# Sorting according to prices for typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So currently I'm developing an e-commerce website and I'm dealing on how to sort the products according to the lowest price up to the highest. I'm having trouble right now with it because I don't know where to start and my knowledge is not up to par, yet.

This is my lines of code right now:

```
<main role="main" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="1000">
<div class="jumbotron section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <div><strong>Shop by Product</strong></div>
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" routerLink="/shop">View All</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/shop/recently-added">New Arrival</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/shop/category/Necklaces">Necklaces</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/shop/category/Bracelets-Anklets">Bracelets and Anklets</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/shop/category/Earrings">Earrings</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/shop/category/Rings">Rings</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/shop/best-sellers">Bestsellers</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/shop/category/Other">Others</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-start flex-wrap" *ngIf="products$">
          <div class="card mx-2" *ngFor="let product of products$; let i = index" [routerLink]="['/product/', product._id]">
            <div class="img-hover-zoom"> <img src="{{product.imageUrl}}" class="img-fluid card-img-top" /></div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text">
                <a>
                  <span style="font-weight: bold;">{{ product.name }}</span>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="card-title">Php {{ product.price }}</div>
              <p *ngIf="product.stock_quantity == 0" style="color: red;font-size: 12pt;">Out of stock</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <select>
          <option selected value="undefined" disabled>
            Choose Category
          </option>
          <option value="l2h">Price: Low to High</option>
          <option value="h2l">Price: High to Low</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a routerLink="/shop" id="back-to-top" class="back-to-top" style="display: inline;">
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-up pt-3 pl-2 ml-2"></i>
</a>
```

*UPDATE - the `products$` `typescript`

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductService } from '../../services/product.service';
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroupDirective,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  NgForm,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material/core';
import { Product } from '../../models/product';
import { size } from '../../models/sizes';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { FixedSizeVirtualScrollStrategy } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
//import { AuthService } from '../../auth.service';

export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(
    control: FormControl | null,
    form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null
  ): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return !!(
      control &&
      control.invalid &&
      (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted)
    );
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-product',
  templateUrl: './admin-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-product.component.css'],
})
export class AdminProductComponent implements OnInit {
  products$: Product[];
  errMess: string;
  galleryForm: FormGroup;
  searchForm: FormGroup;
  imageFile: File = null;
  @ViewChild('labelImport')
  labelImport: ElementRef;
  name = '';
  description = '';
  price = 0;
  category = '';
  stock_quantity = 0;
  featured = false;
  sizes = [];

  // orders
  isLoadingResults = false;
  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(
      (products$) => (this.products$ = products$),
      (errmess) => (this.errMess = <any>errmess)
    );
    this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      searchName: [null, Validators.required],
    })

    this.galleryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      imageFile: [null, Validators.required],
      name: [null, Validators.required],
      description: [null, Validators.required],
      price: [null, Validators.required],
      category: [null, Validators.required],
      sizes: [null, Validators.required],
      stock_quantity: 0,
      featured: false,
      orders: 0,
    });
  }

  onFileChange(files: FileList) {
    this.labelImport.nativeElement.innerText = Array.from(files)
      .map((f) => f.name)
      .join(', ');
    this.imageFile = files.item(0);
  }

  addSize(s) {
    this.sizes.push(s);
  }

  search() {
    this.productService.setSearchQuery(this.searchForm.get('searchName').value)
    console.log(this.productService.getSearchQuery())
    this.router.navigate(['admin/adminProduct/search'])
  }
  onFormSubmit() {
    this.isLoadingResults = true;
    this.productService
      .addGallery(this.galleryForm.value, this.imageFile, this.sizes)
      .subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          if (res.body) {
            document.getElementById('close').click(); // close modal
            this.router.navigate(['/admin/adminProduct/', res.body._id]); // navigate to product detail page
            this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(
              (products$) => (this.products$ = products$),
              (errmess) => (this.errMess = <any>errmess)
            );
          }
        },
        (err: any) => {
          console.log(err);
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
        }
      );
    this.galleryForm.reset();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, 
Could you please elaborate more? Where is that data?

Comment: `let product of products$` seems weird. should be `let product of products$ | async` or `let product of products`. Please show how is filled `products$`, you should do sorting here.

Comment: Plase edit your question to add details

Comment: What do you mean by the data? @Tiago

Comment: the fiddle still contains only the HTML, not the typescript part...

Comment: I added the typescript part @Random

Comment: Thank you, you got good answers now then. Please also remove the `$` in `products$`. The dollar sign is meant to show the variable is an observable. Here, it is not an observable, it is the content of an observable.

Comment: but if I remove it, the products wont show up in the page @Random

Comment: you have to remove the dollar in the HTML too, it's just a variable name.

Comment: Oh I forgot tho, sorry bro.

Answer (score 2):

Add below function under `.ts` file

```
sortProductByPrice(option){
   if(option.value =='l2h'){
     this.products$.sort((a, b) => Number(a.price) - Number(b.price));
   }else if(option.value =='h2l'){
     this.products$.sort((a, b) => Number(b.price) - Number(a.price));
   }
}
```

and update your view `.html` file to call this function

```
<select (change)="sortProductByPrice($event.target)" >
  <option selected value="undefined" disabled>Choose Category</option>
  <option value="l2h">Price: Low to High</option>
  <option value="h2l">Price: High to Low</option>
</select>
```

Comment: There was no sorting that happened once I clicked on an option.

Comment: it would be great if you could create stackblitz and share link here

Comment: [idk if I did the right thing but here u go, its my first time using stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3mdcfn?file=src/app/app.module.ts) @suresh

Comment: do you mean the whole project itself? @suresh

Comment: [try this] (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-56wqvv?file=src/shop/shop.component.ts)

Comment: check this demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ddppem?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Finally, it works now! Thank you @suresh. Additional if I may, what if I would add another function to it like sorting it alphabetically, how would I do it then?

Comment: you can create function like `sortByName(opt){ this.products.sort(function (a, b) {
    return ('' + a.name).localeCompare(b.name);
}) }`

Comment: Then I'll just reverse the code to make a function that will sort Z to A?

Comment: just swap `a` and `b`

Answer (score 0):

You bind the products object to the list using ngFor directive. You can sort the products object according to ascending or descending order after getting the value to that object.

```
this.products$.sort((a, b) => (a.price > b.price) ? 1 : -1)
```

or

```
this.products$.sort((a, b) => (a.price < b.price) ? 1 : -1)
```

Comment: So I just have to insert that on the function for the sorting part? how about the output?